# Turning variables from a list nested in a data frame into columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have a `tbl_df` for which one column is a list of named variables (which themselves are mostly lists). Preferably using `tidyverse` code, I would like to apply a function over a set of these variables, and turn the output of each of these function calls into a new column in the data frame (kind of like what `mutate_at` does, but for these nested variables).

For example, my current data resembles something like this:

```
d <- tibble(
  l = list(list("a"=list("a1","a2","a3","a4"), 
                "b"=list("b1","b2","b3")),
           list("a"=list("x1","x2"), 
                "b"=list("y3")))
)

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  l         
  <list>    
1 <list [2]>
2 <list [2]>
```

I would like to apply functions to the variables in `d$l` (i.e., `a` and `b`) in the same way that `mutate_at` does when you give it multiple functions, automatically creating new columns that are named after the variables that created them. For example, one function I would like to apply would return their lengths as new columns, i.e.:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  l            n_a   n_b
  <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 <list [2]>    4.    3.
2 <list [2]>    2.    1.
```

Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?  So far I've been doing stuff like this:

```
d %>%
  mutate(n_a = purrr::map(l, ~length(.$a)) %>%
           purrr::simplify(),
         n_b = purrr::map(l, ~length(.$b)) %>%
           purrr::simplify())
```

But I don't want to have to write that out for every variable in `l` (the real data has ~24 variables).

**EDIT: Also, to be clear, the example of getting the lengths is just *one* function that I'd like to apply. I really want a more general way of applying *arbitrary* functions on arbitrary *subsets* of the variables in `l`.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lengths` to extract elements' length without looping through them; And use `bind_cols` instead of `mutate` to add multiple columns to the data frame:

```
d %>% bind_cols(map_dfr(.$l, ~ as.list(lengths(.))))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  l              a     b
#  <list>     <int> <int>
#1 <list [2]>     4     3
#2 <list [2]>     2     1
```

Or use `compose` to chain `as.list` and `lengths`:

```
d %>% bind_cols(map_dfr(.$l, compose(as.list, lengths)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  l              a     b
#  <list>     <int> <int>
#1 <list [2]>     4     3
#2 <list [2]>     2     1
```

---

Notice this method dynamically check the names for your list, if element with specific names are missing, the result gives `NA`:

```
d <- tibble(
    l = list(list("a"=list("a1","a2","a3","a4")),
             list("a"=list("x1","x2"), 
                  "b"=list("y3")))
)

d %>% bind_cols(map_dfr(.$l, ~ as.list(lengths(.))))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  l              a     b
#  <list>     <int> <int>
#1 <list [1]>     4    NA
#2 <list [2]>     2     1
```

Comment: This is great, and totally solves my problem with getting the lengths, but is there a more general solution when I want to do things beside getting lengths?  
For example, it seems that it's lucky that `lengths` returns names, but other functions generally won't. Additionally, it seems like selecting only certain variables within `l` might be difficult?

Comment: In that case, you can wrap another `map` in `map_dfr`. `d %>% bind_cols(map_dfr(.$l, ~map(., length)))` and replace `length` with your custom function.

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks a ton!
Is there an easy way to run the functions on a subset of the variables in `l` though?

Comment: Say if you want to subset `subset_var = c('a', 'b', 'c')` and then you can index the list with `[]`, `d %>% bind_cols(map_dfr(.$l, ~map(set_names(.[subset_var], subset_var), length)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `transpose` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package and the `lengths` function.

```
bind_cols(d, map(transpose(d$l), lengths))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   l              a     b
#   <list>     <int> <int>
# 1 <list [2]>     4     3
# 2 <list [2]>     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sapply` and assign the result to your new columns:

```
d[,c("a","b")] <- t(sapply(d$l,lengths))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#            l     a     b
#       <list> <int> <int>
# 1 <list [2]>     4     3
# 2 <list [2]>     2     1
```